# Converting a JSON output into an end-user readable format

Tags: json, variables, converters

At current, I am trying to build a license script that calls my licensing API. When a call is made, a JSON output is returned. For example:-

```
{"result":null,"error":{"message":"Error explanation","code":101}}
```

Is there a way that I can convert this into a readable format via PHP so that it looks something like:-

```
License Error: *Error Message Here* (Error Code: *Error Code Here*)
```

as if I was able to do the following:

```
<?PHP
echo $errorMessage; // Show's the "Error explanation" message.
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a JSON parser?

Comment: So many non-questions, so few downvotes.

Comment: I can't use a decoder as it's my own script and needs to be done in-line. Brian, not a helpful comment really.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

did you try googling anything?

```
$json = '{"result":null,"error":{"message":"Error explanation","code":101}}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->result; // null
```

I'm not that familiar with PHP output on JSON, but I imagine something like:

```
print $obj->error->message //Error explanation
print $obj->error->code //101
```

I am not sure about the exact PHP syntax but that's basically how it works.

Comment: I did try Googling. I can't understand the syntax via the phpNET website. I was hoping for an explanation.